# Create 1 row dataframe from dictionary, with three columns and attach variable to first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a set of data as follows:

```
fruit_dict = {'apples': 12.0, 'pears': 14.0, 'oranges': 5.0, 'lemons': 2.0}
```

I would like to create a dataframe of these items with the title of each fruit as a column as well as having one DATE column, like so (capitalised column titles needed):

```
 DATE         APPLES   PEARS   ORANGES   LEMONS
 2017-09-01   12.0     14.0    5.0       2.0
```

I have created the necessary variable for the date as follows:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(today)
```

However when I try and create a dataframe from the dictionary, I end up with:

```
apples 0 12.0
pears  0 14.0
oranges 0 5.0
lemons 0 2.0
```

The code I try to use to create said frame is:

```
fruit_price = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fruit_dict, orient='index').stack()
fruit_price.columns = ['DATE','APPLES', 'PEARS', 'ORANGES', 'LEMONS']
print(fruit_price)
```

If you have any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First merge dictionaries for `Date` column and then pass to `list` in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = {**{'date': today}, **fruit_dict}
fruit_price = pd.DataFrame([d]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.upper())
```